# Measure time with C# (.Net Core)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I know this question has been asked more than once, but I'm not sure if the results I'm having are right. The operation seems too fast, so I'd like to double check if that's really it.

I have a routine that splits a string into a `List<byte[]>`. I wanted to check the time it takes for the operation, so I modified the code to be like the following:

```cs
// Deserializes base64 received from POST service
var str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonText>(body).text;

Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// parseText is a routine that splits str into
// byte[] of maximum size 100 and puts them into
// a List<byte[]> that is then returned 
commands = DummyClass.parseText(str);

stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan timespan = stopWatch.Elapsed;

Console.WriteLine(timespan.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("0.0###"));

...
```

I ran the routine using a 8000 character string and expected a couple miliseconds op time, but surprisingly the whole operation runs to at most 0.8ms which I expected to be a whole lot slower.

Am I reading the measurements wrong? Does 0.8 means 8ms? Did I do something wrong while measuring the time?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use something like `TotalSeconds`, what does it look like?

Comment: If TotalMilliseconds = 0.8 then it's 0.8 ms. I think your machine should be able to do several clock cycles in that span. You run the test memory so it seems correct at first sight. Changing release and debug modes should have a small impact. You could run it many times and take the average to be sure

Comment: @TimothyG, 0,0005 on average.

I'm also thinking that's the case. I builded for release to be sure but the results are about the same. I find it strange because I was doing the same routine before with Qt and I had something like 3ms on average, so I expected about the same level of performance.

Comment: Well, I think that answers your question. :)

Comment: Normally for a performance analysis you want to do something in a loop, especially in .NET where JIT overhead will potentially dominate a first call. Do it 1000 times and see if you're still seeing approximately the same numbers (well, x1000)

Comment: If what you're trying to do is benchmark that parser, you should consider using a proper benchmarking tool such as Benchmark.NET. That will painlessly run the code many times, provide standard deviation, graphs, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
TimeSpan timespan = stopWatch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine(timespan.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("0.0###"));
```

Why not try

```
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0} ms",stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

You want milliseconds, you have them in stopwatch class directly - no need to visit string.format and timespan libraries.

Comment: It would eliminate the question, removing the possible confusion, if it's the formatting or is it the conversion ect.. You'd be printing a pure number thus be sure it's milliseconds, and not something else, that got wrongly formatted or smth

Comment: Nope, same thing. Actually it shows 0 because of rounding.

Comment: Hi Tutch, I meant just to replace the first 2 lines in my answer with the last line. At a will guess the format part of your first code is wrong - try ToString() instead of ToString("0.0###") ???!1

Answer (score 1):

I think that your operation runs much faster than 1 ms, to measure such small values use timer ticks:

```
stopWatch.ElapsedTicks
```